# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "duda" y "pregunta"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

No entiendo por qué los maestros siempre preguntan estas dos cosas:

> ¿Tienen alguna pregunta o duda?

Mi conocimiento me dice que son lo mismo pero si así fuera no preguntarían las dos cosas.

Comment: Es una formula muy común. Creo se usa así por énfasis.

Answer (score 5):

**Inflexiones de 'pregunta' (n): fpl: preguntas**

> Del verbo preguntar: (conjugar) pregunta es: 3ª persona singular
>   (él/ella/usted) presente indicativo 2ª persona singular (tú)
>   imperativo preguntá es: 2ª persona singular (vos) imperativo
>
> Diccionario de la lengua española © 2005 Espasa-Calpe: pregunta
>
> f. Petición o demanda de información,interrogación: no tengo respuesta
>   a tus preguntas. Cada uno de los puntos de un examen o cuestionario:
>   he dejado en blanco la sexta pregunta.
>
> Diccionario de la lengua española © 2005 Espasa-Calpe:

**Inflexiones de 'duda' (n): fpl: dudas**

> Del verbo dudar: (conjugar) duda es: 3ª persona singular
>   (él/ella/usted) presente indicativo 2ª persona singular (tú)
>   imperativo dudá es: 2ª persona singular (vos) imperativo
>
> Diccionario de la lengua española © 2005 Espasa-Calpe: duda
>
> f. Vacilación e indecisión ante varias posibilidades: tengo dudas
>   sobre si ir o quedarme. Sospecha: existen serias dudas sobre su
>   implicación en la desaparición del dinero. Cuestión que se propone con
>   ánimo de solucionarla o resolverla: expuso sus dudas. sin duda loc.
>   adv. Ciertamente: sin duda, este camino es más seguro que aquel otro.
>
> Diccionario de la lengua española © 2005 Espasa-Calpe:

Como ves, la duda es lo que uno **tiene** y la pregunta es lo que uno **hace** para disipar esa duda.

La expresión correcta debiera ser: *si tienen alguna duda, pregunten* o algo similar.