# Translate Shakespeare: "To be or not to be, that's the question"

Tags: traducción

The problem is that I don't know if  *question* means "doubt" or "problem". *Question* today is mostly used for "pregunta" in Spanish, but in Spanish we know this quote as:

> *Ser o no ser, esa es la cuestión.*

I think it's mistranslated because "cuestión" doesn't really mean *question*, which is instead "pregunta". The beginning of the phrase is translated correctly though.

Comment: According to **Wikipedia** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_be,_or_not_to_be), the first edition (the 'First Quarto', 1603) is slightly different:
"To be, or not to be, **I there's the point**,
To Die, to sleep, is that all? ..."

Comment: Somewhat related: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre “duda” y “pregunta”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17992/12637)

Comment: @user13560 Thanks, but I'm not asking about that edition or that phrase, as clear in my question.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Thanks it is somewhat related, but this is between "cuestion" and "pregunta" no between "cuestion" and "duda".

Comment: Sorry, I was not trying to say that you could find your answer in that other question. I was only linking the two questions as they are similar.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo To be honest, you expressed correctly the first time, because it says "somewhat related" ! :). I shouldn't have responded, sorry.

Comment: @Santropedro: I know, your question is crystal clear. It was a pedantic comment I shouldn't have posted. Sorry. On the other hand, I have often seen it translated as "Ser o no ser, **he aquí el dilema**" or "... **he aquí el problema**". See for instance  http://blogsdelagente.com/todo-es-relativo-imprevisto-y/2010/06/12/ser-o-no-ser-hamlet-shakespeare-monologo/

Comment: This might not be something widely known, especially outside of English literature circles, but the phrase '*To be or not to be*' is more a reference to possible suicide and as such, (and perhaps fitting its archaic language) the use of the verb "haber" might fit, with its old-fashioned synonymity with "existir"

Answer (score 5):

Puesto de otra manera:

> La cuestión que estamos discutiendo es si debemos ser o si no debemos ser.
>   La pregunta que tenemos ante nosotros es, ¿ser o no ser?

Una pregunta es algo bastante directo, es decir, una oración interrogativa.  Una cuestión es algo a problematizar, discurrir y discutir, que es lo que se hace después de este verso (que es el inicio de unos 30 versos de Hamlet).

Answer (score 5):

To give some context to what is easily one of the most famous quotes in history:

> "To be, or not to be" is the opening phrase of a **soliloquy** spoken by Prince Hamlet [...]
>
> Although called a soliloquy, Hamlet is far from alone since Ophelia is pretending to read while she waits for Hamlet to notice her, and [...]
>
> Even so, **Hamlet seems to consider himself alone**.
>
> <sub>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_be,_or_not_to_be)</sub>

So Hamlet is asking a question to himself. We could change the sentence, maintaining all the meaning, by saying:

> To be or not to be, that is the *conundrum*:
>
> Whether 'tis Nobler in the mind to suffer [...]

since a *conundrum* is `"a confusing and difficult problem or question; a question or problem having only a conjectural answer; a riddle"`.

And by doing that I hope it is clearer to understand the difference when translating to Spanish "question" as `cuestión`, instead of `pregunta`.

From the [definition of "cuestión"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bb1zrQ1):

> **Pregunta** que se hace con intención dialéctica para averiguar la verdad de algo.
>
> **Problema** que debe ser resuelto.
>
> Oposición de términos lógicos o de razones respecto a un mismo tema, que **exigen detenido estudio** para resolver con acierto.

We can see how the definition of `cuestión` explains the term as a "pregunta", but a `pregunta` that you make in order to learn something (like a rhetorical question in order to help someone understand something or to make them think, like in the Socratic method).

Thus, "question" has been correctly translated in this context, since Hamlet is not asking anything to anybody present in the room. He is more or less thinking aloud and philosophizing. He is talking about this philosophical problem, this conundrum.

You could have used `pregunta` in the translation, losing little meaning, but for Hamlet this is not actually "*a* question" (*una* pregunta / *la* pregunta) but "**THE** question" (**LA** [gran] pregunta). Thus, it is more a conundrum and philosophical riddle than a question *per se* (even a rhetorical question), and the translation favors the appropriate term `cuestión` over `pregunta`, `duda`, `tema`, etc.